# Using RMI on the windows 7

Tags: java

I am a new with using RMI on windows 7, and I want to run my project with RMI to show "HelloWorld", but I could not run it, because I have got the following error. anyone can help me please.
also I have used JDK 1.6.

My error is:

java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello_Stub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways you can get this exception:

1. When constructing/exporting your remote object. In this case it means you haven't supplied a port number parameter to `super(int port...)` if your remote object extends `UnicastRemoteObject,` or to `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` otherwise, **and** you haven't generated a stub via `rmic`. Note that if you supply a port number parameter, even zero, you don't need to run `rmic` at all.
2. When binding/rebinding the remote object to the Registry (in the server). In this case it means you haven't supplied a port number etc as above, but you have generated the stub, otherwise you wouldn't get this far because of (1), *but* the _Stub class isn't available to the Registry on its CLASSPATH. The simplest solution to this is to run the Registry in the same JVM, via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`. Note that the return value of this method needs to be stored somewhere where it won't be garbage-collected, e.g. in a static variable.
3. When looking up the Registry (in the client). In this case it means you haven't supplied a port number etc as above, but you have generated the stub, otherwise you wouldn't get this far because of (1) and (2), *but* the _Stub class isn't available to the client on its CLASSPATH. Solution: deploy it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use the [rmic.exe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/rmic.html) to generate your remote classes stubs. These are not automatically generated by your Java compiler (javac.exe).

You can define an [Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) (called rmic) to simplify your life and make sure your stubs are automatically generated.

If you are using Eclipse you can even include this task as part of your building process so that you can be sure they are generated every time your code is compiled. Most probably other IDEs offer similar features.

Comment: `rmic.exe` has not been needed since Java 1.5 / 5.0.

Comment: I have done it, but after running server file I have got it.. I do not know what is my problem..

Comment: I have done it, but after running server file I have got it.. I do not know what is my problem..

Comment: @ChrisDennett It is still needed if you don't supply a port number parameter when constructing (super(port)) or exporting. See the preamble to UnicastRemoteObject for why.

Comment: Port has nothing to do with whether rmic is needed or not. It's not needed.

Comment: @ChrisDennett You are mistaken about this and when you will read the citation I provided you will see why.

Comment: Oh, okay. I see your answer. I thought you were the OP going on about something completely different, then I looked at the name :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you're perhaps following an outdated version of this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html. If that's not the case, check your Java version on the command line (`java -version`).

Comment: Indeed. there is no need for rmic, it was deprecated in an older version of Java. It's not used anymore. This was before there were the dynamic programming facilities that there are now.

Comment: Also make sure you *are* using 1.6. Type `java -version` on the command line to confirm.